# ERROR: a 'NAMESPACE' file is required

Tags: r, namespaces, r-faq

I am trying to install some R packages on a Linux machine using

```
R CMD INSTALL -l <ourRlibrarylocation> <path where I saved the packagename.tar.gz file>
```

and I see an error message:

```
ERROR: a 'NAMESPACE' file is required
```

I am using R 3.0.1. Please help, I am new to R and just downloaded these packages for customers.

One example:

```
 R CMD INSTALL -l /abcde/R/R-3.0.0/library /home/RFILES/PKG/UScensus2000tract_0.03.tar.gz
* installing *source* package âUScensus2000tractâ ...
ERROR: a 'NAMESPACE' file is required
* removing â/abcde/R/R-3.0.0/library/UScensus2000tractâ
```

Answer (score 42):

[According to the `R` documentation for writing extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Package-namespaces), all packages destined for version 3.0.0 and later must contain a `NAMESPACE` file. If you download an `R` package that gives you the above error, here's what you should try:

Untar the package:

```
tar -xvf the_package.tar.gz
```

Add a `NAMESPACE` file with the line `exportPattern( "." )`:

```
cd the_package
echo 'exportPattern( "." )' > NAMESPACE
cd ..
```

Re-tar the package:

```
tar -zcf the_package.tar.gz the_package
```

Try and install it again.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Great solution! On Windows,  you can use `echo exportPattern( "." ) > NAMESPACE` instead of `echo 'exportPattern( "." )' > NAMESPACE`.

Answer (score 4):

I actually just hit the same thing when compiling R-3.0.1.  It looks to be that the package version that I was using was out of date.  This was for `proto`:

```
# /var/local/R-3.0.1/bin/R CMD INSTALL -l /var/local/R-3.0.1/lib64/R/library proto_0.3-9.2.tar.gz
* installing *source* package ‘proto’ ...
ERROR: a 'NAMESPACE' file is required
* removing ‘/var/local/R-3.0.1/lib64/R/library/proto’
```

But there was a newer version for proto (0.3-10) which worked fine:

```
# ../var/local/R-3.0.1/bin/R CMD INSTALL -l ../var/local/R-3.0.1/lib64/R/library proto_0.3-10.tar.gz
* installing *source* package ‘proto’ ...
** package ‘proto’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** demo
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
   ‘proto.Rnw’
   ‘protoref.Rnw’
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (proto)
```

I had an older install of R (2.15), which the older proto package worked with:

```
# /var/local/R-2.15.0/bin/R CMD INSTALL -l /var/local/R-2.15.0/lib64/R/library proto_0.3-9.2.tar.gz
* installing *source* package 'proto' ...
** Creating default NAMESPACE file
** R
** demo
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
   'proto.Rnw'
   'protoref.Rnw'
** testing if installed package can be loaded
```

It looks like the older version of R actually creates the missing NAMESPACE file, but the new version bails.  Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 3):

I found the following link more useful:
[How should I deal with "package 'xxx' is not available (for R version x.y.z)" warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-for-r-version-x-y-z-wa)

> **6. The package is out of date**
>
> It may have been [archived](http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/) (if it is no longer maintained and no longer passes [`R CMD check`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/topics/PkgUtils) tests).
>
> In this case, you can load an old version of the package using [`install_version()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/devtools/topics/install_version)
>
> ```
> library(devtools)
> install_version("foobarbaz", "0.1.2")
> ```
>
> An alternative is to install from the github CRAN mirror.
>
> ```
> library(devtools)
> install_github("cran/foobarbaz")
> ```

Comment: For package `GeneTS`, `install_github` throws an error of `ERROR: a 'NAMESPACE' file is required `. Is it expected?

Answer (score 1):

One can now use `remotes::install_url()` or `remotes::install_local()`.

It installs dependencies and generates the `NAMESPACE` file automatically.