# R Installing prior verison package NAMESPACE file missing

Tags: r, networking, namespaces

I'm using Windows and is trying to install latentnet package in version 2.1.1. You can locate the package in the following link:

https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/latentnet/latentnet_2.1-1.tar.gz

I tried to use:

```
    install_version("latentnet", version = "2.1-1", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

Error message received:

```
Downloading package from url: http://cran.us.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/latentnet/latentnet_2.1-1.tar.gz
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages, but no version of Rtools compatible with R 3.5.1 was found. (Only the following incompatible version(s) of Rtools were found:3.5)

Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools from http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/.
Installing latentnet
"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.1/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet  \
  CMD INSTALL "C:/Users/wawa0001/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpCig4et/devtools504261651b3/latentnet"  \
  --library="C:/Users/wawa0001/Documents/R/win-library/3.5" --install-tests 

* installing *source* package 'latentnet' ...
ERROR: a 'NAMESPACE' file is required
* removing 'C:/Users/wawa0001/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/latentnet'
In R CMD INSTALL
```

Then I tried to download the package to my local drive and used following command:

```
install.packages("latentnet_2.1-1.tar.gz", repos = NULL)
```

I received another error message:

```
Installing package into �C:/Users/wawa0001/Documents/R/win-library/3.5�
(as �lib� is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'latentnet' ...
ERROR: a 'NAMESPACE' file is required
* removing 'C:/Users/wawa0001/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/latentnet'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/wawa0001/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/latentnet'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘latentnet_2.1-1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

It seems I need to create a 'NAMESPACE' file, and I referred to this post:
[ERROR: a 'NAMESPACE' file is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17196225/error-a-namespace-file-is-required)

However, command `tar` does not exist on my PC externally or internally and I do not know a way to get it to execute.

Could anyone suggest a way to download the early version of the package? I currently have R 3.4.4.

Thanks!

Comment: Newer versions of R have stricter requirements for pacakges. If you want to use an older R package, try also using an older version of R (whatever was around at the time of the package version you want to use). You say you have R version 3.4.4 but the message above says "win-library/3.5" which would indicate you have at least R version 3.5

Comment: @MrFlick Can I use R studio with an older version of R without un- installing 3.5?

Comment: You can have different versions of R installed side-by-side on your machine.

Comment: @MrFlick I have a mac and the earliest I can go back is 3.3. Latentnet package is still asking for a NAMESPACE file.

Comment: Version 2.1.1 of that package look alike it was released in Feb 2008. At that time R version 2.6 was current (very old). Since R 3.0 (at least) all packages require namespace files. Why do you need such an old version? You would have to manually create the missing files yourself if you want to fun that code.

Comment: @MrFlick I'm trying to re-run code from this research paper: https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v024i05. The latentent version it used was 2.1.1 Some of the features used in the paper are no longer available in the latest version.